# Custom Control with Data Type property Issue

Tags: user-controls, c#-3.0, properties, types, numeric

I'm building a custom user control.  One of the properties  must allow the end user to select the numeric data type such as int, short, long, double....

I'm having a problem figuring out what to use as an internal property type, so that when the user selects the DataType option in the property box it will give them a drop down list of all the numeric types.

I've tried a few variances... This one below, when compiled displays the DataType property as grayed out.  It won't allow me to select or
enter a value.

```
   private System.ValueType _DataType;
   public System.ValueType DataType
   {

       get { return _DataType; }
       set
       {

           _DataType = value;
       }
   }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property editor has no idea how to edit the type. The easiest way to fix it is to use a type it does know how to edit, like a string or an enum. Enum probably fits best with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I would rather not use an enum, especially since the numeric data types are a system stuct.  Also the enums don't like to have reserved words used in them.  Their must be a way to sovle this easily.???

Comment: I wouldn't call it easy but you can create a custom editor for a custom type in a propertygird. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx shows how its done.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an enum - I think their should be a better answer than this.  Same functionality is found when designing datasets in the designer.  When you select the data type you can choose int and others.